# PNG and GIF image won't appear in website but JPG does

Tags: html, image, web

My website is atomicscroll.com.

In the atomicscroll directory, I have a subdirectory called 'img'.  In this subdirectory, I have three files:  as.gif, as.png, as.jpg.

http://atomicscroll.com/img/as.gif  doesn't work.  The same address with as.png doesn't work either.

But http://atomicscroll.com/img/as.jpg works just fine.

This behavior is consistent across Firefox, Chrome, and Internet Explorer.  Can someone tell me why this would be?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The links are working.  Did you fix your problem?

Answer (score 0):

its because the format of your image is jpg. if you want it to be a .gif file you must create or convert the jpg to that format. if the file is already there, make sure you match the file extension exactly as it appears.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Actually, I used Microsoft paint to save the image in the three different formats.

Answer (score 0):

hmm

I believe I had similar issues once before. if you have Photoshop, then open the image with photoshop. Hopefully it can open.

Then save for web - make sure the button Convert to SRGB is selected.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I unfortunately do not have Photoshop, but I do have Gimp.  I tried opening with that; it opened fine.  I then exported as different filetypes; still unable to see them on the web.